# swiftui how to apply usage of multiple StateObject

Tags: swiftui, observableobject, environmentobject, property-wrapper-published

prettyNew to SwiftUi and combine, how could be possible having more than one class initialized and accessible in the whole app? This code is not working, when I tap the button I get the error about

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type OneSharedClass
> found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for OneSharedClass may be missing
> as an ancestor of this view.

which is the right way to use them?I'd like these two classes could be talk, ut with no retain circles.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SharingData: App {

    @StateObject var oneSharedClass = OneSharedClass()
    @StateObject var otherSharedClass = OtherSharedClass()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(oneSharedClass)
                .environmentObject(otherSharedClass)

        }
    }
}

//Code for the rest of the app


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
   
    @EnvironmentObject var oneSharedClass: OneSharedClass
    @EnvironmentObject var otherSharedClass: OtherSharedClass

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("name: \(oneSharedClass.name) \(oneSharedClass.isLogged ? "✅" : "❌")")
            
            Button("Tap") {
                otherSharedClass.testFunc()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(OneSharedClass())
    }
}

class OneSharedClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name: String = "N/D"
    @Published var isLogged: Bool = true
}


class OtherSharedClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var oneSharedClass: OneSharedClass
    
    @State var myArray = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]
    
    func testFunc() {
        if oneSharedClass.isLogged {
            print(myArray)
        }
    }
    
}
```

UPDATE: version where I pass the reference to a single method, so the otherSharedClass remains independent, but not sure if @StateObject in "App" is required.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SharingData: App {
    
    /*@StateObject*/ var oneSharedClass = OneSharedClass()
    /*@StateObject*/ var otherSharedClass = OtherSharedClass()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(oneSharedClass)
                .environmentObject(otherSharedClass)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var oneSharedClass: OneSharedClass
    @EnvironmentObject var otherSharedClass: OtherSharedClass
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            
            Text("name: \(oneSharedClass.name) \(oneSharedClass.isLogged ? "✅" : "❌")")
                .background(oneSharedClass.myColor)
            
            Button("Tap oneSharedClass") {
                oneSharedClass.testFunc()
                otherSharedClass.testFunc(oneSharedClass: oneSharedClass)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

class OneSharedClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name: String = "N/D"
    @Published var isLogged: Bool = true
    
    @Published var myColor: Color = Color.red
    
    func testFunc() {
        isLogged.toggle()
    }
}


class OtherSharedClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var myArray = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]
    
    func testFunc(oneSharedClass: OneSharedClass) {
        print("isLogged read from oneSharedClass and printed from other: \(oneSharedClass.isLogged)")
        print(myArray)
        oneSharedClass.myColor = oneSharedClass.myColor == .green ? .red : .green
    }
    
}
```

Comment: In Swift and SwiftUI it's best to stick to structs (like the `View` struct ) and only use a class when you need a reference type (not very often now we have `.task`).

Comment: I updated the question, is that why you mean? It is version where I pass the reference to a single method, so the otherSharedClass remains independent, but not sure if @StateObject in "App" is required. I thought this was the new way swiftui allows me to share classes everywhere I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnvironmentObject` and `State` are only for SwiftUI views you cannot use the property wrappers in a `class`.

Change `State` to `Published`.

And you can pass the other as an argument when needed

```
func testFunc(onesharedclass: OneSharedClass)
```

If you want to share a class with an entire app you have to change your approach and disconnect the value of a `class` from the UI.

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/

Comment: I updated the question, is that why you mean (referring to the method)? It is version where I pass the reference to a single method, so the otherSharedClass remains independent, but not sure if @StateObject in "App" is required. I thought this was the new way swiftui allows me to share classes everywhere I need

Comment: @biggreentree StateObject is the only safe way to initialize an ObservableObject in a View so yes keep it. But DI is a better approach, it will simplify your code greatly after a simple setup.

Comment: @biggreentree if I answered your question can you please click on the green checkmark and maybe upvote?

Comment: done, just a last question before I clean up, regarding the initializing of a Class, used as "brain" for views: you mention StateObject in a view, but I'll do it in the "App" Struct. is this the same? so better do it that way? I ask because in many courses on swiftui they do not talk about DI but usage of '@StateObject', '@ObservedObject' and so on.

Comment: @biggreentree same thing, yes I know about what is commonly out there. DI doesn’t contradict those it just expands it. A lot of people out there are just putting stuff on the internet they don’t use any real architecture. And overlook that Apple actually encourages value types for View State management.